# Codeigniter HMVC module hierarchy

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I am learning to use codeigniter for my project. After finishing the tutorial from [kode-blog.com](https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/codeigniter-model) Then i learn wiredesignz HMVC. Right now I ended up having a structure like this

modules

-admin

--cotroller

---admin controller

---product controller

-auth(ion_auth)

-user

--controller

---user controller

---product controller

It sort of make sense to me as the modularity is based from user perspective but then i will end with 2 big modules admin and non-admin with the content asically the same except using different method (ex: user only able to view the product not adding it).

Now with the repeating sub-module i think i am wrong. My second thought would be to structure it like this

-admin

-user

-product

-ion_auth

Which one is correct?